# Why does my legend use purple for my geom_line when it should be red?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code produces a stacked area plot with one line graph just like I intended, however it produces a legend that doesn't match the color of the line graph. How do I fix this? Thanks!

[image: legend on the graph]

```
ggplot(data=revenue, aes(x=Date, alpha=0.1)) +
  geom_area(aes(y=SENSE.revenues + ORB.revenues + SENSE.refills + ORB.refills, 
                fill=" ORB Refills"),colour="Black")+
  geom_area(aes(y=SENSE.revenues + ORB.revenues + SENSE.refills, fill=" ORB 
                Revenue"),colour="Black")+
  geom_area(aes(y=SENSE.revenues + SENSE.refills, fill=" SENSE 
                Refills"),colour="Black")+
  geom_area(aes(y=SENSE.revenues, fill=" SENSE Revenues"),colour="Black") +
                labs(title="Projected Revenues", subtitle="SENSE and ORB", 
                     y="Revenue ($Thousand)") +          
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Revenue Type") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1))+
  scale_x_discrete(name ="Date", limits=dates) +                   
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Purples")+
  scale_alpha(guide = 'none')+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  geom_line(aes(y=Returns, fill=" Revenues Net of Returns"), colour="Red", 
                size=0.7)
```

Comment: I never used ggplot, but the only place where is written "Red" is on the last line (`geom_line`). `scale_fill_brewer` only says "Purples".

Comment: Line doesn't have fill only colour.

Comment: @Rodrigo adding other colors in the `scale_fill_brewer` line doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: @PoGibas I tried to add fill outside and inside the `aes()` line for `geom_line` but neither worked.

Comment: Isn't it `"red"` with lower case `"R"`? R (the language) is case sensitive.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I thought that too at first, but his image seems to say it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to plot multiple things in a `ggplot` graph, it's almost always best in the long run to rearrange your data so you can plot them all at once with an aesthetic distinguishing them, rather than asking for multiple almost-identical `geom_`s ... here's a rough example.

Make up some data:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(Date=1:4,
                 SENSE.revenues=rpois(4,3),
                 ORB.revenues=rpois(4,3),
                 SENSE.refills=rpois(4,3),
                 ORB.refills=rpois(4,3),
                 Returns=rpois(4,3))
```

Convert from wide to long:

```
ddg <- tidyr::gather(dd[,1:5],"type","revenue",-Date)
```

(using `dd[,1:5]` leaves off the Returns; if you wanted to commit to tidyverse you could use `select(-Returns)` here)

Plot with a single `geom_area()`, distinguished by `fill`: use `position="stack"` to get all of the areas plotted one on top of the other ... plot the red line separately, with a faked colour aesthetic (we override the colour value and label with `scale_colour_manual()`).

```
ggplot(data=ddg,
       aes(x=Date,y=revenue))+
    geom_area(position="stack",aes(fill=type))+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Purples", name="revenue type")+
    geom_line(data=dd,aes(y=Returns,colour="junk"))+
    scale_colour_manual(values="red",
                        labels="Returns",
                        name="")
```

[image]